# How do I run python 3.X with atom? (Windows)

Tags: python, tkinter, atom-editor

I'm currently trying to do something with tkinter on python, which isn't available for 2.7. How can I run a newer version of python on atom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered [atom-python-run](https://atom.io/packages/atom-python-run)? It allows you to run Python code by pressing F5.

Comment: Just tried it, gave an error with "ImportError: No module named tkinter," and also defaults to 2.7.17

Comment: Are you able to run your code from a console by doing `Python {fileName}`? Because that's all `atom-python-run` does.

Comment: Install Python 3 and make sure its installed path is added to `path` environment (before Python 2).  Then restart `atom` and `atom-python-run` will use it.

Comment: Bless you. I tried installing Python 3, but Atom kept defaulting to Python 2.7. After adding it to path and moving it above Python 2.7, it worked.